# RoR Time into Seconds Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time

Let's say I want to find out the difference in seconds between two times. One of the times is the `created_at` attribute of the element, and the other time is a random fixed time in the past. How would I find the difference between the two, and transform it into seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucky for you the `-` operator in ruby returns you an float which is the difference in seconds.

```
difference_in_seconds = x.created_at - random_time_in_past
```

Comment: what form should `random_time_in_past` be? Should it be passed to the `datetime` method?

Comment: `random_time_in_past` should be a variable that is either an instance of `Time`, `Date`, `DateTime`. It can also be a `Numeric` but that does something slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as:

```
time = Time.now
offset = time - record.created_at
```

`offset` will now be a Float which is the difference in seconds between the two compared Time objects.